# Why do we need a temporary node while inserting values in a node in Linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I was creating a **binary tree** using linked list in java, which inserts the value according to the height of the tree i.e if the height is even or odd.  I wrote a code which initially had no temporary node for insertion of values to the root node and further left or right subtree nodes. But when I displayed this tree, output had no root node as if it was overwritten. 
Below is the code of my initial program. Concentrate on `public void insert_node()` function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class binary_tree {
private TreeNode root;
private int height = 0;
public static class TreeNode {
    private int data;
    private TreeNode left;
    private TreeNode right;
    public TreeNode(int user_input) {
        this.data = user_input;
    }
}


public void insertNode(TreeNode newnode) { // HERE....I have used only root.

    if (root == null) {
        root = newnode;
        height += 1;
        return;
    }
    if (height % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println(height);
        while (root.left != null) {
            root = root.left;
        }
        root.left = newnode;
        height += 1;
        return;
    }
    while (root.right != null) {
        root = root.right;
    }
    root.right = newnode;
    height += 1;
}
public void display(TreeNode rootnode) {
    TreeNode temp = rootnode;
    if (temp == null)
        System.out.println("Tree Empty !!!");
    else {
        System.out.println("press 1 for LEFT SUBTREE \npress 2 for RIGHT SUBTREE.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ch = sc.nextInt();
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println(temp.data + " $");
            if (ch == 1)
                temp = temp.left;
            else
                temp = temp.right;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Height of the tree = " + height);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    binary_tree bt = new binary_tree();

    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(50);
    bt.insertNode(newNode);

    TreeNode newNode2 = new TreeNode(10);
    bt.insertNode(newNode2);

    TreeNode newNode3 = new TreeNode(100);
    bt.insertNode(newNode3);

    TreeNode newNode4 = new TreeNode(5);
    bt.insertNode(newNode4);

    TreeNode newNode5 = new TreeNode(1000);
    bt.insertNode(newNode5);

    bt.display(bt.root);
}
```

}

**Output**

```
press 1 for LEFT SUBTREE 
press 2 for RIGHT SUBTREE.
3
10 $
1000 $
Height of the tree = 5
```

You can see in the above code, that the `50 $` is missing which was supposed to be the root node.
Now, if I use a temporary node which in my case is `current_node` then this root node sustains somehow. See in the code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class binary_tree {

private TreeNode root;
private int height = 0;

public static class TreeNode {
    private int data;
    private TreeNode left;
    private TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(int user_input) {
        this.data = user_input;
    }
}

public void insertNode(TreeNode newnode) {
    TreeNode current_node = root;   //THIS IS THE TEMPORARY NODE    
    if (current_node == null) {
        root = newnode;
        height += 1;
        return;
    }
    if (height % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println(height);
        while (current_node.left != null) {
            current_node = current_node.left;
        
        }
        current_node.left = newnode;
        height += 1;
        return;
    }
    while (current_node.right != null) {
        current_node = current_node.right;
    }
    current_node.right = newnode;
    height += 1;
}

public void display(TreeNode rootnode) {
    TreeNode temp = rootnode;
    if (temp == null)
        System.out.println("Tree Empty !!!");
    else {
        System.out.println("press 1 for LEFT SUBTREE \npress 2 for RIGHT SUBTREE.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ch = sc.nextInt();
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println(temp.data + " $");
            if (ch == 1)
                temp = temp.left;
            else
                temp = temp.right;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Height of the tree = " + height);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    binary_tree bt = new binary_tree();

    TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(50);
    bt.insertNode(newNode);

    TreeNode newNode2 = new TreeNode(10);
    bt.insertNode(newNode2);

    TreeNode newNode3 = new TreeNode(100);
    bt.insertNode(newNode3);

    TreeNode newNode4 = new TreeNode(5);
    bt.insertNode(newNode4);

    TreeNode newNode5 = new TreeNode(1000);
    bt.insertNode(newNode5);

    bt.display(bt.root);
}
```

}

**Output**

```
press 1 for LEFT SUBTREE 
press 2 for RIGHT SUBTREE.
3
50 $
100 $
1000 $
Height of the tree = 5
```

So anyone who can tell me what's happening here? What difference does that `current_node` is making?

Comment: `current_node` is not a *temporary node*. It is a *reference variable* used to track the progression (iteration) through the *existing nodes* of the tree. There is no temporary node object created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do we need a temporary node while inserting values in a node in Linked list?

Because you are traversing to the leaves of the tree here:

```
while (current_node.left != null) {
    current_node = current_node.left;
}
current_node.left = newnode;
height += 1;
```

In these lines of code, you are trying to find the leftmost leaf so as to insert `newnode`, right? You want to use a variable to keep track of which node you are currently on, and "go left" by doing `someVariable = someVariable.left;`.

You *could* use `root` to keep track of where you are at, but `root` already has a purpose - to record the root of the tree! If you did `root = root.left;`, you are making the left node of the original root be the new root! Say your tree was:

```
    50
   /  \
  10  100
```

Doing `root = root.left` deletes most of it:

```
    10
```

This is problematic because this means your tree essentially "forgets" about a part of the tree. Technically, The 50 and 100 nodes still exists and 50 is still connected to 10, but your `binary_tree` object doesn't have access to it anymore. The only point of access it has is `root`, which you have now set to the node 10.

What actually happens in your program is: it correctly inserts 50, 10, and 100, then when adding 5, tries to traverse down the left subtree. This makes the root "10", and adding 5 becomes:

```
    10
   /
  5
```

It then adds 1000 correctly:

```
    10
   /  \
  5   1000
```

Hence it prints 10 and 1000.

Using a brand new variable solves this problem, because the brand new variable has nothing to do with `root`.